# chai: expected headers to include application/json

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to run a test case with mocha + chai. Here is my test case:

```
it('it should login a user', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
        .post(constant.USERS_PATH + constant.LOGIN_PATH)
        .set('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({
            USERNAME: 'abc',
            PASSWORD: 'xyz'
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(res).should.be.json;
            expect(res.body[0]).should.have.status(200);

            done();
        });
});
```

I'm expecting result to be:

```
[{STATUS: true}]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"message":"uncaughtException: expected headers to include 'application/json'
```

I also tried to change:

```
.set('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

to

```
.set('Accept', 'application/json')
```

but still the same error, can't figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem until I realized, I was receiving an invalid response (not a JSON) so my test was actually giving the correct AssertionError: expected headers to include 'application/json'